# NoClassDefFoundError, but the code works and the class exists

Tags: java, maven, aspose, aspose-cells

I have a Maven project and I'm using Aspose cells to manipulate an xlsx file. Aspose is configured through the POM

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
[...]
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>AsposeJavaAPI</id>
            <name>Aspose Java API</name>
            <url>https://repository.aspose.com/repo/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aspose</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspose-cells</artifactId>
            <version>22.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Now, when I test the project as a Java application there is no error. The code runs successfully, but when I execute the generated JAR this is what I get:

```
descrizione sconto
descrizione
codice sconto
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/aspose/cells/SaveOptions
        at src.main.java.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.aspose.cells.SaveOptions
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 1 more
```

The first three rows are the console output of the project, the output files are created too, but that error shows up.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA, Java version: JDK17.0.2, Maven version: Maven 3.8.1

Comment: How do you run the JAR? Are all dependent libraries listed in the `Class-Path` attribute of the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, and in the right position relative to the JAR? Or did you create an uberjar?

Comment: Did you bundle or reference the aspose library with your jar?

Comment: simply by java -jar file.jar
this is the .MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: Maven JAR Plugin 3.2.2
Build-Jdk-Spec: 11
Class-Path: aspose-cells-22.6.jar
Main-Class: src.main.java.MainClass

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding details in the comments. Is aspose-cells-22.6.jar located in the same directory as your jar?

Comment: No, there isn't the aspose jar in the directory

Comment: Then there is your problem (as an aside, if you want people to get notified, use `@<username>`). Configure Maven to copy the dependencies to the output directory, or do it yourself, or create an uberjar (aka fatjar) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by changing the build in my pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>eu.tvrsier.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                    <id>default-cli</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>eu.tvrsier.MainClass</mainClass>
                        <launcher>app</launcher>
                        <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                        <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                        <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                        <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                        <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

before those changes i was creating a package, so i had maven-plugin instead of maven-assembly-plugin in the artifact ID, and I've added the executions block too